# 2 or More ConnectionString on App.config MySQL VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, app-config

I got a code that can return the **ConnectionString** from the `App.Config` in my VB.Net project. My problem is whether I call **online1** or **offline2** the **offline2 value is being called or more likely a default**.

I want to get a connection string base on `GetConnectionString([ConnectionString Name])`

```
Public Shared Function GetConnectionString(ByVal strConnection As String) As String
    'Declare a string to hold the connection string
    Dim sReturn As New String(" ")
    Dim connections As ConnectionStringSettingsCollection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    'Check to see if they provided a connection string name
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strConnection) Then
        For Each connection As ConnectionStringSettings In connections
            If connection.Name = strConnection Then
                'Retrieve the connection string fromt he app.config
                sReturn = connection.ConnectionString
            Else
                'Since they didnt provide the name of the connection string
                'just grab the default on from app.config
                sReturn = connection.ConnectionString
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return sReturn
End Function
```

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="online1" connectionString="SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=lto_db; UID=root; PASSWORD=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="offline2" connectionString="SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=lto_db; UID=root; PASSWORD=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
Public Shared Function GetConnectionString(ByVal name As String) As String
    Dim connStrings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Then
        If connStrings.Count > 0 Then
            Return connStrings(0).ConnectionString
        Else
            Throw New Exception("No default connection string")
        End If
    Else
        Dim conn = connStrings(name)
        If conn Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("No connection string named " & name)
        Return conn.ConnectionString
    End If
End Function
```

You'll need a reference to System.Configuration if you don't have one already

The problem with your code is that if the connection name is null or empty you don't even execute the loop and don't return a default (you just return ""). If they do specify a name and it's not the first then you return the default and exit even if there are more connections to check.